# Google Analytics tracking SagePay referrals

Tags: google-analytics, opayo

I am having an issue where Google Analytics is tracking SagePay referrals. I have followed [this](http://spencerbean.com/shopify-excluding-paypal-as-referrer-in-google-analytics/) tutorial a while ago and added the following URLs to the exclusion list:

- `checkout.sagepay.com`
- `sagepay.com`
- `live.sagepay.com`

yet all the sales statistics since then are still attributing `checkout.sagepay.com / referral` and I can't work out why.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: I can't tell from your post if you realize this, but the settings will not affect data that has already been collected.

Comment: @EikePierstorff Thanks for the response, yeah I made the change a while back but it's still happening

Comment: Did you work this out?  Adding them to exclusion list might help https://www.en.advertisercommunity.com/t5/Google-Analytics-Tracking-Goals/Conversion-not-showing-in-Goal-Funnel/td-p/918586#